# Ecommerce application and solution

Tags: php, joomla, e-commerce

Here's my predicament. I'm working with a designer who has a very unique layout for his ecommerce site. It's kinda like a table/tier based system where you buy a certain amount of points. I need the ability to have user accounts etc and it will all be in joomla. There's many options such as magento, virtuamart etc. but basically what I'm saying is... will it be possible with any particular platform to transform the products so much so that can still use the platform? here's a screen shot...

http://www.one2designs.com/images/screen.png

Basically It needs to some way integrate into joomla, allow for user profiles etc, and I guess be so customizable that it can be transformed into that look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Joomla and Virtuemart allow for 100% of customisation of the templates used. The process is simply:

- Design
- Cut and slice into HTML
- Build Joomla template, product pages.

Further, the screenshot shows simply a list of 7 products, so either Table with 7 columns or a ul, li construct will work.

Is there anything else product wise you need to manage? It doesn't look like people will actually add more than 1 product to their "shopping cart", so a simple form manager like RSForm may achieve the same purpose. There are E-Commerce plugins for most newer form managers now and it should also not be too hard to link up third party payment gateways as a one off.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your image, that is simply a product with various options that are user selected. You would need to change the way the product options are displayed to fit the design, but other than the display, there is nothing unusual about a product with many options. Everything below the radio buttons is pretty much irrelevant as it is only option details. Virtuemart could be made to do this fairly easily.